# How to implement DependencyProperty in UserControl that update source on LostFocus?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties, updatesourcetrigger

I was on to implement a `UserControl` called PhoneBox that contains a single `TextBox`, some custom logic, and has a DependencyProperty called PhoneNo. It was to be used in in a two-way binding scenario with a `LostFocus` for `UpdateSourceTrigger`. So I wrote the following code -

XAML (UserControl):

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="txtPhone" MinWidth="120" MinHeight="23" LostFocus="txtPhone_LostFocus" GotFocus="txtPhone_GotFocus"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-Behind (UserControl):

```
public partial class PhoneBox : UserControl
{
    //Some Code

    static PhoneBox()
    {
        FrameworkPropertyMetadata phoneNoMetadata =
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPhoneNoChanged),
                                          new CoerceValueCallback(CoercePhoneNoValue));
        PhoneNoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("PhoneNo", typeof (string), typeof (PhoneBox),
                                                       phoneNoMetadata,
                                                       new ValidateValueCallback(ValidatePhoneNoValue));
    }

    public readonly static DependencyProperty PhoneNoProperty;
    public string PhoneNo
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PhoneNoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PhoneNoProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnPhoneNoChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PhoneBox phoneBox = (PhoneBox)d;
        string newValue = (string)e.NewValue;

        phoneBox.txtPhone.Text = newValue;
    }

    private static object CoercePhoneNoValue(DependencyObject d, object basevalue)
    {
        return basevalue;
    }

    private static bool ValidatePhoneNoValue(object value)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void txtPhone_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetValue(PhoneNoProperty, this.txtPhone.Text);
    }

    private void txtPhone_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtPhone.Text))
            this.txtPhone.Text = this.FilterText(txtPhone.Text);
    }

    private string FilterText(string text)
    {
        //Some cutom logic
    }

    //Some more Code
}
```

XAML (Consumer):

```
<pbc:PhoneBox PhoneNo="{Binding Path=User.Phone, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

It works. But my question is, the way I used the `txtPhone_LostFocus` event handler to set proerty value (and in turn update source), is that appropriate? Is there any more appropriate way to do this? I'm a novice in this `DependencyProperty` thing, so any guiding, suggestion, comments will be thankfully appreciated.

Comment: You do realize LostFocus is the default on TextBoxes?

Comment: I do. The point here is not specific to `TextBox`.

Comment: With regard to the Binding syntax: Mode=TwoWay is default for TextBox.Text, you could go without that. RelativeSource, though complicated, is the way to go here. You could even declare a XAML-namespace for your assembly and use the UserControls exact type, like {x:Type my:PhoneBox}, in order to be more specific. Normally, I'd use ElementName binding syntax, but then you need to give the UserControl an x:Name attribute, and it creates conflicts if you set this in its own XAML and then client XAML which uses the UserControl tries to set x:Name on it from outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WPF way to handle this situation is to have a Binding between your UserControl's `DependencyProperty` and the `TextBox` declared in the UserControl's XAML file. This is also where you would set the `LostFocus UpdateSourceTrigger` (which you don't have to, since it is the default behaviour). You'd declare the Binding on the `TextBox` (i.e. inside the UserControl), so client code using the UserControl would be free to set another binding on the PhoneNo property (from outside of the UserControl). Also, if your CoerceValue callback only returns the base value, better go without it from the start.

This might be what David meant initially...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would indeed rather use the `UpdateSourceTrigger` enumeration in the DP metadata than the `LostFocus` EventHandler, and get rid of all the redundant methods: it's always better to let WPF do those things for you if you can: it'll do them better and faster.

Plus in this case, I personally find it a lot easier to read in the metadata than in the lostFocus method. But this is a matter of taste I guess.

**edit:** no no, I understood what you meant, But I might not have been clear myself in my answer. Here is roughly what I would do (just to give you a hint, that would require some tuning in your case):

```
public partial class PhoneBox : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PhoneNoProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "PhoneNo",
        typeof (string),
        typeof (PhoneBox),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus),
        new ValidateValueCallback(ValidatePhoneNoValue));

    public string PhoneNo
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PhoneNoProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PhoneNoProperty, value); }
    }

// ... your code here.

}
```

Comment: and how exactly the `TextBox`, which ACTUALLY holds the text, is gonna be affected by this? how i'm gonna get & set the text? this won't cause the `TextBox` to loose it's focus. have you try it in real application code?

Comment: it actually depends on the structure of your usercontrol and how you plan on using it. Say you have more sub controls in your usercontrol and you want to update the property when the focus goes from the textbox to one of the other subcontrols, in this case, yes, you're stuck with the LostFocus event option since the usercontrol itself will remain focused even if the textbox is not anymore. But if you just have the textBox like you wrote, you cannot be in the position where the userControl is focused but the textBox is not, and you can use the second option.

Comment: "...if you just have the textBox like you wrote, you cannot be in the position where the userControl is focused but the textBox is not" - you really have some logic there, now can see. but the case is, whether i provide the `UpdateSourceTrigger` through the `MetaData` constructor, or through the XAML the `PhoneNo` doesn't update on `LostFocus`. i've posted the whole code, you can test it yourself. the only case when the `PhoneNo` gets updated on `LostFocus` is when i use `SetValue()` through that `txtPhone_LostFocus` event handler.

Comment: but it's also true that with your suggested implementation if the `UserControl` looses focus there's nowhere in the code we are interacting with the `TextBox` whose value is what we need to use for the `UpdateSourceTrigger`.